# about the User Interface resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm developing an user interface of my application . and for the designing I'm using devXpress controls. and I'm developing application in the C# windows forms.

I've developed the user interface of my application but when I'm changing my computers resolution setting then that time my user interface design changes according to the size of all the controls. But it should not happened with the user interface. how to resolve this problem? is there any solution for resolving this problem?

Comment: Maybe add some screenshots?  Your question is very vague at this point.

Comment: how can i accept the answer of particular question if the answer is not fulfilling my requirements?

Comment: You don't.  But, if they do (or they help lead you to the answer) it is best practice to accept them as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not to set absolute positions for your controls, but instead use Control.Dock and Control.Anchor properties to position them relative to their parent and/or siblings.

Comment: The OP wrote, he does not want to UI design to change when resolution changes. You are suggesting to adapt the UI to resolution ( in a well defined manner, of course), but that is not what he was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to scale instead of resize.

Did you [try changing the DPI](http://www.ehow.com/how_5145260_change-dpi-resolution.html) of your desktop instead of the resolution?

WinForms might support that (I haven't tried it) but in general WinForms forms do not scale. WPF apps support scaling very well because WPF uses vectors.